# System Won't Boot If I Change from RAID ON to AHCI (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, bios, raid, ahci

[System Configuration - SATA Operation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjpk1.jpg)

I am trying to enable AHCI for a "secondary system experiment" so that the drives will be recognized in the installer. Thing is, when I enable AHCI windows won't boot at all. The BIOS warns upon the change that I might have to reinstall Windows all over again with AHCI enabled this time. Is this true?

Comment: "won't boot at all" - what exactly happens? "It says that I might have to reinstall Windows all over again with AHCI enabled this time" - what says so? An exact quote would be helpful.

Comment: The BIOS issues a warning upon changing the option. Then when it tries to boot it just keeps loop restarting to the DELL logo

Answer (score 0):

Switch back to IDE in your BIOS so it will boot.

Start REGEDIT and look for this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\storahci\StartOverride
```

Change the 0 DWORD value from `3` to `0`.

Shut down, go back to your BIOS and switch it to AHCI.

Comment: There is no option for IDE as you can see from the screen shot. I am able to boot since I went to the BIOS and changed it back to RAID ON option. 

Should I still try your recommendation?

Comment: @Kyriacos I guess that daidai meant _RAID On_ rather than _IDE_.